# automatic wizard update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP wizard which have 3 tabs.
1st tab have some variable which are input of second tab's  database function.The problem is that on page loaded all the page content is load with default parameter and when values of variable of tab 1 changes, second tabs content don't get updated accordingly.so how can i achieve that when ever variable of 1st tab changes second tab data update automatically.
Thanks

Comment: How can we help you if you don't even post any code to be analyzed?